# Issue with Recursion in Java. Method is returning empty list

Tags: java, selenium, recursion, arraylist

I am trying to return an array list from my method which actually use recursion to populate that list. But the method always return an empty list. I've checked in debug mode the list is getting populated in second go but still method return 0 element.

Below is code for my method.

```
private static List<WebElement> checkMonth(WebDriver driver) {
    List<WebElement> months = driver.findElements(By
            .xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Caption']"));
    List<WebElement> daysList = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    for (WebElement monthEl : months) {
        if (monthEl.getText().contains(month)) {
            daysList.addAll(driver.findElements(By
                    .xpath("//div[contains(text(),'" + month
                            + "')]/..//div[@aria-disabled='false']/div")));
        }
    }

    if (daysList.size() == 0) {
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//span[@class='DayPicker-NavButton DayPicker-NavButton--next']"))
                .click();
        checkMonth(driver);
    }

    return daysList;
}
```

Comment: does it returns `null` or an empty list? I suspect it's an empty list.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez I saw this code, but the text and title clearly state it returns `null`

Comment: Based on my experience, it's not the best to return WebElements, as the page might get refreshed or for any other reason, the element(s) might become stale. I suggest you capture their values and return them instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a recursive call

```
checkMonth(driver)
```

but ignore the `List` returned by that call.

Perhaps you want to add the output of that call to the overall output returned by your method (the `daysList` list):

```
daysList.addAll(checkMonth(driver));
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could take the initialization of the `List` out of the function to the parent scope, and then add the elements recursively